# Can I open page(NON-Visualforce) by POST method?

Tags: apex, visualforce, php, post

We want to open page(NON-Visualforce) by POST method.

1. User open Visualforce page, and click 「submit」 button.
2. This button call Apex class( or js? ) , other page open by POST method.
3. Other page is created by FUEL PHP.

Can I this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it several ways.

## Visualforce

Simply use a regular `<form>` tag:

```
<form action="myotherserver/page" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Continue"/>
</form>
```

## Apex

You can use an HttpRequest method:

```
public void doSubmit() {
  HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
  req.setMethod('POST');
  req.setEndpoint('myotherserver/page');
  req.setBody(...);
  req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
  req.setHeader('Content-Length',''+req.getBody().length());
  HttpResponse res = new Http().send(req);
}
```

Comment: I see. I will try this. Thank you!